# Why is attribute changing of HTML using JS not working?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, shopify

I want to disable the button or change the attribute of the field so that if there are less than 12 characters in the input field it will disable the button
I tried everything i know of.(commented)
(Possible Duplicate of - [Can't change html attribute with external script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229913/cant-change-html-attribute-with-external-script) )

Html code

```
<button name="button" type="submit" id="continue_button" class="step__footer__continue-btn btn" aria-busy="false">
  <span class="btn__content" data-continue-button-content="true">Continue to shipping</span>
  <svg class="icon-svg icon-svg--size-18 btn__spinner icon-svg--spinner-button" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"> <use xlink:href="#spinner-button"></use> </svg>
</button>
```

JS code -

```
$("#checkout_shipping_address_address1").attr('maxlength','15');
      var valueLength = $('#checkout_shipping_address_address1').val();
      if(valueLength.length < 12){
     //   console.log(valueLength.length);
     //   $("#checkout_shipping_address_address1").aria-invalid="true";
       // var attrChange = $("#error-for-address1");
      //  $("#checkout_shipping_address_address1").innerHTML("aria-describedby" = attrChange);
       // $("#checkout_shipping_address_address1").innerHTML("aria-descibedby = attrChange"); 
     //   $("#checkout_shipping_address_address1").setAttribute("aria-invalid", "true");
      //  $('#continue_btn').attr("disabled", true);
      //  $('#continue_btn').disabled = true;
     //   $('#continue_btn').prop('disabled', true);
      }
      else
      {
       // $('#continue_btn').disabled=false;
      }
```

The attribute is not changing on the webpage neither can i disable the button.

**Note- I cant change HTML/CSS code as i dont have access to it**

P.S - I am quite new to JS/JQuery.

Comment: What is the HTML code of the field and button?

Comment: <button name="button" type="submit" id="continue_button" class="step__footer__continue-btn btn" aria-busy="false"><span class="btn__content" data-continue-button-content="true">Continue to shipping</span><svg class="icon-svg icon-svg--size-18 btn__spinner icon-svg--spinner-button" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"> <use xlink:href="#spinner-button"></use> </svg></button>

Comment: The id of your button is `id="continue_button"`, whilst in your JQuery you look for `$('#continue_btn')`, that's one reason it might not be working.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but it's still working, and in inspect i cant see the added/changed attribute.I used             $('#continue_button').disabled= true;

Comment: you should be doing `$('#continue_button').prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti Still working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input needs an event handler function (added with [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)) so that something happens when the user changes the input value:

```js
$("#checkout_shipping_address_address1").attr('maxlength', '15').on('input', function() {
  $('#continue_button').prop('disabled', $(this).val().length < 12);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="checkout_shipping_address_address1" />
<button name="button" disabled type="submit" id="continue_button" class="step__footer__continue-btn btn" aria-busy="false">
  <span class="btn__content" data-continue-button-content="true">Continue to shipping</span>
  <svg class="icon-svg icon-svg--size-18 btn__spinner icon-svg--spinner-button" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"> <use xlink:href="#spinner-button"></use> </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: Got your concept, but its not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put an event listener on your text input and I propose to you a vanilla JS solution :

1. Disable button by default
2. Check value length on input
3. Change disabled value according to the result

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#continue_input");
const button = document.querySelector("#continue_button");
input.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  if(event.target.value.length > 11) {
    button.removeAttribute("disabled");
  } else {
    button.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  }
});
```

```css
.step__footer__continue-input {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<input id="continue_input" class="step__footer__continue-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter 12 characters here">
<button id="continue_button" class="step__footer__continue-btn btn" type="submit" name="button" aria-busy="false" disabled="true">
  <span class="btn__content" data-continue-button-content="true">Continue to shipping</span>
  <svg class="icon-svg icon-svg--size-18 btn__spinner icon-svg--spinner-button" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><use xlink:href="#spinner-button"></use></svg>
</button>
```